# Error on returning message from bot (Forbidden)

Tags: botframework

I am creating a bot on facebook and as per the logs I am having , The message is reaching the bot but when the bot is responding I am getting the below error

"System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Authorization for Microsoft App ID   failed with status code Forbidden    at Microsoft.Bot.Connector.JwtTokenRefresher.d__2.MoveNext()"

I tried on facebook/skype and it's the same error. I added message.From but still facing some issue.

Here is my message returning code.

```
Activity replyMessage = message.CreateReply();
replyMessage.Text = "Text";
replyMessage.TextFormat = "plain";
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(replyMessage);
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

return response;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you [registered the bot](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html#registering) on the Bot Framework portal? If so, make sure that you are using the correct MicrosoftAppId and MicrosoftAppPassword in your project's web.config. The error you are having it seems an authentication issue, which basically means that your settings in the web.config are not the expected ones

Comment: Yes its there, I also clicked the button Test the connection to your bot and it said "Endpoint authorization succeeded"